# getBoundingClientRect() is not a function

Tags: javascript, function

i'm trying to get the window hight and the y rect of the element i got a message '.getBoundingClientRect() is not a function'

hint : here is the complete project so u can see my problem.
i'm getting the error in the log
here is my code:

```js
var messageGetter = $('.message');
var clientH = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
var memoY = messageGetter.getBoundingClientRect().height;
alert(memoY);

$(document).scroll(function(){
  if(messageGetter.isInViewport()){
    messageGetter.fadeIn('slow').css('visibility', 'visible');
  }

})
```

```html
  
    <div class="lower-container">

  <div class="message message-right">
     <p class="message-content">I agree that your message is awesome!</p>
     <div class="message-timestamp-right">SMS 13:37</div>
     <div class="ball-right"></div>
     </div>

     <div class="message message-left">
        <p class="message-content">I agree that your message is awesome!</p>
        <div class="message-timestamp-right">SMS 13:37</div>
        <div class="ball-left"></div>
        </div>

       <div class="message message-right">
          <p class="message-content">gggg</p>
          <div class="message-timestamp-right">SMS 13:37</div>
          <div class="ball-right"></div>
       </div>

       <div class="message message-left">
          <p class="message-content">I agree that your message is awesome!</p>
          <div class="message-timestamp-right">SMS 13:37</div>
          <div class="ball-left"></div>
          </div>
    </div>





    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I assume this is because `$('.message')` is returning an array of elements rather than an element, try doing `$('.message')[0].getBoundingClientRect()`

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is happening because under the jQuery hood `$(".message")` is calling `document.querySelectorAll('.message')` which returns an array of the elements, rather than an element itself, therefore when you try to call `.getBoundingClientRect()` it's not a function because you're not directly accessing any element.

Try doing

`$(".message")[0].getBoundingClientRect()`

Comment: Glad it worked! If you could please mark this answer as the correct solution it would help other people with similar issues find the answer aswell